# Use Swagger API validation with Serverless Framework

Tags: aws-lambda, swagger, aws-api-gateway, serverless-framework, request-validation

I want add an api validation to the serverless aws-nodes template and nothing I have tested until now has worked very well.

My current approach is to overwrite the existing api-gateway, which is generated by the serverless framework, with a yml/json swagger definition that contains my models for the validation. This works for me when I test it in the API-Gateway UI, but on external requests the api don't validate the request for the lambda-proxy.

When I use normal lambda the api gateway also passthrough the request body without validation or transformation.

My current swagger api definition with validation:

```
  swagger: "2.0"
  info:
    title: feedback
    version: '1.0'

  schemes:
  - https
  produces:
  - application/json
  x-amazon-apigateway-api-key-source : HEADER

  x-amazon-apigateway-request-validators:
    full:
      validateRequestBody: true
      validateRequestParameters: true
    body-only:
      validateRequestBody: true
      validateRequestParameters: false
  x-amazon-apigateway-request-validator: full

  # Custom 400 response with validation feedback
  x-amazon-apigateway-gateway-responses:
    BAD_REQUEST_BODY:
      statusCode: 400
      type:
        application/json: 
      responseTemplates:
      application/json:
        |-
          {
              "message": $context.error.messageString,
              "validation":  "$context.error.validationErrorString",
              "statusCode": "'400'"
          }

  # request structure
  paths:
    /feedback:
      post:
        # validation definition
        x-amazon-apigateway-request-validator: body-only
        parameters:
        - in: body
          name: Create ...
          required: true
          schema: 
            "$ref": "#/definitions/Model"
        responses:
          '200':
            description: validation succeeded
          '400':
            description: validation failed

        x-amazon-apigateway-integration:

          uri: "arn:aws:apigateway:{api-region}:lambda:path/2015-03-31/functions/arn:aws:lambda:{lambda-region}:{konto-id}:function:{function-name}/invocations"

          passthroughBehavior: when_no_match
          httpMethod: POST
          requestTemplates:
            application/json: '{"statusCode": 200}'
          type: aws
      get:
        responses:
          '201':
            description: list all Data
            content:
              application/json:
                schema:
                  type: array
                  items:
                    feedback:
                      $ref: "#/definitions/Model"
          '401':
            $ref: "#/definitions/UnauthorizedError"
        x-amazon-apigateway-integration:
          uri: "arn:aws:apigateway:{api-region}:lambda:path/2015-03-31/functions/arn:aws:lambda:{lambda-region}:{konto-id}:function:{function-name}/invocations"
          passthroughBehavior: never
          httpMethod: POST
          type: aws_proxy

  # definition of the request/respons model with validation
  definitions:
      Model:
        type: object
        properties:
          topic:
            $ref: "#/definitions/Topic"
          text:
            type: string
            minLength: 1
            maxLength: 250
        required:
          - topic
          - text
      Topic:
            type: string
            enum: 
              - xyz
```

My api definition from my serverless.yml

```
functions:
  create:
    handler: feedback/create.create
    events:
     - http:
         path: feedback
         method: post
 list:
    handler: feedback/list.list
    events:
      - http:
          path: feedback
          method: get
```

> the lambda functions only read/write feedback from/to an DynamoDB

Has someone an idea how I can add some kind of api validation to my serverless project without using small plugins (serverless-reqvalidator-plugin) or how to solve the problem with the data transformation ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok the solution for the problem that the validation works with the internal test but not with an external request was very obvious. I forgot to deploy the new api-definition.

```
aws apigateway create-deployment --rest-api-id {api-id} --stage-name dev
```

Also I have changed my API-definition. I now inegrate to my Post request an normal lambda. This is the only way, I can make sure that only json content gets validated and afterwards get passed through to the lamda function. Because I use no lambda-proxy the request event gets transformed from the api-gateway, so I have to define an request template, that put the whole request body in an new request.

```
 requestTemplates:
      application/json: '{"statusCode": 202, "body": $input.body}'
```

With this way I also transformed the lambda response in an predefined api response with Cors headers.

I the end my solution is:

1: Write a swagger api definition:

```
  swagger: "2.0"
  info:
    title: xxxxxx
    version: '0.0.0'

  schemes:
  - https
  produces:
  - application/json

  x-amazon-apigateway-api-key-source : HEADER

  # Define which parts of the request should be validated
  x-amazon-apigateway-request-validators:
    full:
      validateRequestBody: true
      validateRequestParameters: true
    body-only:
      validateRequestBody: true
      validateRequestParameters: false

  # Custom response model from the api-gateway that return validation error string 
  x-amazon-apigateway-gateway-responses:
    BAD_REQUEST_BODY:
      statusCode: 400
      type:
        application/json:
      responseParameters: # CORS Headers
          gatewayresponse.header.Access-Control-Allow-Credentials : "'true'"
          gatewayresponse.header.Access-Control-Allow-Origin : "'*'"
      responseTemplates:
      application/json: #must be an json string because otherwiese there are some transformation issues
        |-
          {
              "message": $context.error.messageString,
              "validation":  "$context.error.validationErrorString",
              "statusCode": "400"
          }   


  paths:
    /feedback:
      options: 
        description:
          Enable CORS by returning correct headers
        tags:
          - CORS
        x-amazon-apigateway-integration:
          type: mock
          requestTemplates:
            application/json: |
              {
                "statusCode" : 200
              }
          responses:
            "default":
              statusCode: "200"
              responseParameters: # CORS Headers
                method.response.header.Access-Control-Allow-Headers : "'Content-Type,X-Amz-Date,Authorization,X-Api-Key'"
                method.response.header.Access-Control-Allow-Methods : "'*'"
                method.response.header.Access-Control-Allow-Origin : "'*'"
              responseTemplates:
                application/json: |
                  {}
        responses:
          200:
            description: Default response for CORS method
            headers:
              Access-Control-Allow-Headers:
                type: "string"
              Access-Control-Allow-Methods:
                type: "string"
              Access-Control-Allow-Origin:
                type: "string"
      post:
        # validation definition
        x-amazon-apigateway-request-validator: body-only
        parameters:
        - in: body 
          name: requestBody
          required: true
          content:
            application/json:
          schema: # validation model
            "$ref": "#/definitions/Model"
        responses: # response documentation
          '200':
            description: Create ......
            headers: # Header format for the CORS headers
              Access-Control-Allow-Credentials:
                type: "string"
              Access-Control-Allow-Origin:
                type: "string"
        x-amazon-apigateway-integration:
          responses:
            default:
              statusCode: "200"
              responseParameters: # CORS Header
                method.response.header.Access-Control-Allow-Credentials : "'true'"
                method.response.header.Access-Control-Allow-Origin : "'*'"
          uri: arn:aws:apigateway:${AWS::Region}:lambda:path/2015-03-31/functions/arn:aws:lambda:${AWS::Region}:${AWS::account-id}:function:{AWS::lambda-function-name}/invocations
          requestTemplates:
            application/json: '{"statusCode": 202, "body": $input.body}' 
          passthroughBehavior: never # only accept Json Data
          httpMethod: POST 
          type: aws 

      get:
        security: # X-API-Key
          - authorizer: [] 
        responses: 
          '200':
            description: ......
        x-amazon-apigateway-integration: 
          uri: "arn:aws:apigateway:xxx:lambda:path/2015-03-31/functions/arn:aws:lambda:xxx:xxxxxxx:function:function-name/invocations"
          httpMethod: POST
          type: aws_proxy 

  definitions:
    Model:
       # Swagger Model with validation

  securityDefinitions:
    authorizer :
      type : apiKey                         
      name : x-api-key                 
      in : header
```

2: Overwrite the existing serverless api:

```
aws apigateway put-rest-api --rest-api-id {api-id} --mode overwrite --body file://xxxx/api.yml
```

3: Don't forget to deploy the new api:

```
aws apigateway create-deployment --rest-api-id {api-id} --region eu-central-1 --stage-name ...
```